# Why is heroku pg:pull getting stuck at this table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, devise

A Heroku pg:pull seems to keep getting stick on table 'users'. I am using ruby on rails, and postgresql. I am using the devise gem for the users table. 
It gets stuck at:

```
pg_dump: dumping contents of table users
```

This is the schema data for the users table:

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
```

Comment: How many rows are in the users table? Does the process ever exit with an error?

Comment: There's only like 4 or 5 rows, and no, it just stays there forever, I wonder if it has anything to do with the devise gem

Comment: Given that it's stuck on dumping the remote table, it's possible (but not likely) that something has a lock on the table. You can cheek that with heroku pg:locks.

Comment: `pg:locks` is not a heroku command. I have this stuck too. Not only 1 but 2 projects, stuck both on `users` table. Still no solution yet.

Comment: or you might have to use `pg:backups` and `pg:restore` instead. A little cumbersome but works though https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export